# Event not triggered on table's dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/XpVzpM) with table where rows are dynamically added. Each row should trigger event:

```
  $("#tblTest > tbody > tr").on("click", function(e){    
    alert();        
  });
```

This code doesn't work for dynamically added rows. What is the problem?

Comment: Two words **Event delegation**. =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is adding the click to the tr on creation.  You need to instead attack the click to the tbody then filter to tr.

```
  $("#tblTest > tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){    
    alert();        
  });
```

Comment: Switch it to `> tr` as that is what the OP seems to want. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#tblTest > tbody > tr", function(e) {
    alert();
  });
});
```

Comment: You missed a `});` there

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to use the Body for the .on event:

```
  $("body").on("click", "#tblTest > tbody > tr", function(e){    
    alert();        
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

For dinamically added elements you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tblTest > tbody > tr", function(e){    
    alert('test');        
  });
```

Updated **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRpqGg)**.

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically add a row, you must bind a new onClick listener to the added element. Your code only adds the listener to elements already on the page; not newly created elements. Something like this will work fine:

```
var AddRow = function(){
     // add element
     $("#tblTest > tbody").append("<tr><td>Test name</td><td>Last anme</td></tr>");
     // add listener to new element
     $("#tblTest > tbody > tr:last-of-type").on("click", function(e){    
          alert();        
     });
}
```

the :last-of-type psuedo-selector is key to avoid binding multiple listeners to the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation.

```
 $(document).off('click.namespace').on('click.namespace', '#tblTest > tbody > tr', function (e) {
alert();           
  });
```

It will rebind the Events. 
So dynamically appended rows also bind with events.